# Restrictions on the number of edges in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, discrete-optimization

I have been wondering, can you prove that if we suppose in a graph (connected or not) there are no cycles of length 3 (so at least 4) and each vertex has a degree 4 or less, then the number of edges will be less than $\frac{3}{2}*n - 2$ where n is the number of vertices.

I tried using Euler's Formula, namely $v - e + f = k + 1$. If we then take into consideration the restriction on cycle length we get $2f < m$ so we can substitute and get $m < 2n - 4$, however that is not enough and also is not using the fact that each vertex has a degree 4 or less.

I'm sorry, I forgot to tell the graph has to be planar.

Comment: Interesting challenge, thanks, even if it turned out to be false - if you describe briefly how you came to that limit it might highlight some extra hidden condition that does lead to such a limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non-planar counterexample to your hypothesis. the [Folkman graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folkman_graph) is quartic (4-regular, all vertices have degree 4) and has girth (minimum cycle length) of 4. This has 20 vertices and 40 edges.
[image]

---

Adding in the planar requirement, an infinite square grid would obviously not meet your formula, so a large square grid with the corners looped around to each other should also fail... let's try $6\times 6$, which has $36$ vertices and $64$ edges breaks your proposed limit of $\frac{3}{2}*n - 2$:
[image]
... and I could sneak in four more edges to get to $2n{-}4$ in fact, by joining the nodes adjacent to the corners also along each edge.

It's pretty clear that this construction allows a $2n{-}4$ edged triangle-free graph on $n$ nodes for a grid that is $2p\times 2q$ with $p,q>1$, nearly $4$-regular except for $8$ degree-$3$ nodes. The smallest is thus on $16$ vertices with $28$ edges:
[image]

---

Comment: Oh, thank you. Now I see my theory was wrong.